# split() method on state value in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've got **town** value (in an object) like:

```
75000 - Paris Ile-de-France
```

I'm trying to get the second part of my **town** state value using the *split* method:

```
<Text>{this.state.town.split("-")[1].trim() || ''}</Text>
```

But it seems *split* method is taken as an element of the object. I've got this error:

```
Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.
```

Any idea?

UPDATE :

Ok, it's undefined at start point, before I update the state of town.

Now I try to put a condition before it tries to split my string, but I fail. I'm doing this, but it returns an unexpected token:

```
<Text style={styles.selectedTown}>{
      return (this.state.town !== {}) ? this.state.town.split('-')[0].trim() : '';
    }</Text>
```

Comment: `this.state.town.name` is `undefined`

Comment: Sorry I made corrections.

Comment: What does your state look like at that point in time? The error would seem to indicate that there's no `town` property inside of your state.

Comment: Again, this means that town is undefined. Please show that code that you use to intialize this.state.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between undefined and defined as an empty object. Try this:

```
<Text style={styles.selectedTown}>{
      (this.state.town !== undefined) ? this.state.town.split('-')[0].trim() : ''
    }</Text>
```

Comment: It seems you cannot use return in this context.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I adjusted the answer accordingly. You still need to check for undefined.

Comment: Ok, I finally found the solution! I had to remove the ";" symbol at the end! ;)